# Access Denined to acces report server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

My system Architecture as bellow

Single server Having

1.SQL serevr 2014 standard edition

2.Report server

3.Application server i.e(ASP.Net MVC  application server)

when i am trying to access report server through network system getting error 'Access denied'. But same server when calling direct report server URL then there is no error.

In report service Configuration manager service account is Local service.

In reportserver.config file Authentication Type is changed to 'RSWindowsNegotiate'  from 'RSWindowsNTLM' .

Tried with two users having Administrator rights on Server but not able to access the report server and while passing the credentials getting blank screen after changing Authentication type in reportserver.config file .

please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS)? Go to Start - Run -  Services.msc, it should show "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)".

Comment: Installed ssrs and started services as well

Comment: In server meachine I configured reportserver with HTTPS(SSL certification). There it’s running with out any authentication but while I’m running in local meachine which is having access to server meachine there I’m getting credentials dialog box and after providing username and password then getting error you do not have permission to view this directory or page using credentials

Comment: _I’m getting credentials dialog box and after providing username and password_ - Are you sure that the user has the reqd authorisations? If you are on a domain, then it is surely some domain authorisation related issue. Also, in your SQL Server, I hope TCP/IP is enabled (SQL Server Configuration Manager - Protocols for MSSQLServer - TCP/IP - Enabled. Also, double-click - IP Addresses - IPAll - TCP Port = 1433). Also check if TCP port is allowed in firewall/domain/router. It is definitely a non-software issue. Involve your network admin to troubleshoot if you are on a domain.